# How to use Protractor.addMockModule in the e2e test

Tags: angularjs, angular, protractor

I have a typescript test:

```
describe ('User should be able to login', () => {

beforeEach(()=> {
browser.addMockModule('mockLogin', function() {
angular.module('mockLogin', []).value('foo', 'bar');
});
```

My modName is a typescript class:

```
export class mockLogin {
... some code
}
```

I want to use that class but I get complilation error cannot find name angular.

Answer (score 0):

`addMockModule` does not currently work for Angular2 applications. Look for updates in this issue:

- [Support adding mock modules to Angular 2 applications](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3092)

Comment: I know that, but I actually do not want to replace the module, I just want to use some kind of proxy. What if I import angular 1 into the node_modules folder ?

Answer (score 0):

When I did mocking, I used: https://github.com/kbaltrinic/http-backend-proxy

Maybe you could try using that instead of using the addMockModule functionality.